# Replace CURSOR with table variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I am not very good at SQL. I have seen the following stored procedure was taking more than 15 minutes to execute. I have read that CURSOR should be avoided but I don't know how to do that. Is looping through table variable row by row basis is slow like CURSOR operation? Pleas help.

```
SET @GetStudents=CURSOR FOR SELECT nStudentInsessionID FROM GetStudentFullName WHERE cSession=@cSession AND nCampusID=@nCampusID AND nClassID IN (SELECT t1 From @t1) ORDER BY nStudentInsessionID
OPEN @GetStudents FETCH NEXT FROM @GetStudents INTO @nStudentInSessionID
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
     SET @GetDepositIn=CURSOR FOR SELECT t2 From @t2 ORDER BY t2
     OPEN @GetDepositIn FETCH NEXT FROM @GetDepositIn INTO @nDepositID
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
         BEGIN
            SET @GetDepositInGroup=CURSOR FOR SELECT t3 From @t3 ORDER BY t3
            OPEN @GetDepositInGroup FETCH NEXT FROM @GetDepositInGroup INTO @tnDepositInGroupID
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
                 BEGIN
                    SET @GetFeeHead=CURSOR FOR SELECT t4 From @t4 ORDER BY t4
                    OPEN @GetFeeHead FETCH NEXT FROM @GetFeeHead INTO @tnFeeHeadID
                        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
                            BEGIN
                                SELECT @nActualFee=ISNULL(SUM(nAmount),0) FROM FeeGroupDetail WHERE nFeeGroupDetailID IN(SELECT DISTINCT nFeeGroupDetailID FROM FeeStudentFeeGroupRelation WHERE nStudentInSessionID=@nStudentInSessionID  AND nDepositIngroupID IN(@tnDepositInGroupID) AND nDepositIN IN (@nDepositID) AND nFeeHeadID in (@tnFeeHeadID))
                                SELECT @nStudFee=ISNULL(SUM(nAmount),0) FROM FeeStudentFeeGroupRelation WHERE nStudentInSessionID=@nStudentInSessionID AND nDepositIN IN (@nDepositID) AND nDepositIngroupID IN(@tnDepositInGroupID) and nFeeHeadID in (@tnFeeHeadID)
                                IF @Ischeckdate=1
                                    BEGIN
                                        SELECT @nFeePaid=ISNULL(SUM(nFeePaid),0) FROM FeeDepositMaster INNER JOIN FeeDepositDetail ON FeeDepositMaster.nFeeDepositID=FeeDepositDetail.nFeeDepositID WHERE FeeDepositMaster.dFeeDepositDate<=@dDueUpto AND ISNULL(FeeDepositMaster.IsCanceled,0)=0 AND FeeDepositMaster.nStudentInSessionID=@nStudentInSessionID AND nDepositIN IN (@nDepositID) AND FeeDepositDetail.nFeeHeadID in (@tnFeeHeadID) AND nDepositIn IN (SELECT DISTINCT nDepositIn FROM FeeGroupDetail WHERE  nDepositInGroupID in (@tnDepositInGroupID))
                                        SELECT @nConcession=ISNULL(SUM(nConcession),0) FROM FeeDepositMaster INNER JOIN FeeDepositDetail ON FeeDepositMaster.nFeeDepositID=FeeDepositDetail.nFeeDepositID WHERE FeeDepositMaster.dFeeDepositDate<=@dDueUpto AND ISNULL(FeeDepositMaster.IsCanceled,0)=0 AND FeeDepositMaster.nStudentInSessionID=@nStudentInSessionID AND nDepositIN IN (@nDepositID) AND FeeDepositDetail.nFeeHeadID in (@tnFeeHeadID) AND nDepositIn IN (SELECT DISTINCT nDepositIn FROM FeeGroupDetail WHERE  nDepositInGroupID in (@tnDepositInGroupID))
                                        SELECT @nLateFee=ISNULL(SUM(nLateFeeAmount),0) FROM FeeDepositMaster INNER JOIN FeeDepositDetail ON FeeDepositMaster.nFeeDepositID=FeeDepositDetail.nFeeDepositID WHERE FeeDepositMaster.dFeeDepositDate<=@dDueUpto AND ISNULL(FeeDepositMaster.IsCanceled,0)=0 AND FeeDepositMaster.nStudentInSessionID=@nStudentInSessionID AND nDepositIN IN (@nDepositID) AND FeeDepositDetail.nFeeHeadID in (@tnFeeHeadID) AND nDepositIn IN (SELECT DISTINCT nDepositIn FROM FeeGroupDetail WHERE  nDepositInGroupID in (@tnDepositInGroupID))
                                    END
                                ELSE
                                    BEGIN
                                        SELECT @nFeePaid=ISNULL(SUM(nFeePaid),0) FROM FeeDepositMaster INNER JOIN FeeDepositDetail ON FeeDepositMaster.nFeeDepositID=FeeDepositDetail.nFeeDepositID WHERE ISNULL(FeeDepositMaster.IsCanceled,0)=0 AND FeeDepositMaster.nStudentInSessionID=@nStudentInSessionID AND nDepositIN IN (@nDepositID) AND FeeDepositDetail.nFeeHeadID in (@tnFeeHeadID) AND nDepositIn IN (SELECT DISTINCT nDepositIn FROM FeeGroupDetail WHERE  nDepositInGroupID in (@tnDepositInGroupID))
                                        SELECT @nConcession=ISNULL(SUM(nConcession),0) FROM FeeDepositMaster INNER JOIN FeeDepositDetail ON FeeDepositMaster.nFeeDepositID=FeeDepositDetail.nFeeDepositID WHERE ISNULL(FeeDepositMaster.IsCanceled,0)=0 AND FeeDepositMaster.nStudentInSessionID=@nStudentInSessionID AND nDepositIN IN (@nDepositID) AND FeeDepositDetail.nFeeHeadID in (@tnFeeHeadID) AND nDepositIn IN (SELECT DISTINCT nDepositIn FROM FeeGroupDetail WHERE  nDepositInGroupID in (@tnDepositInGroupID))
                                        SELECT @nLateFee=ISNULL(SUM(nLateFeeAmount),0) FROM FeeDepositMaster INNER JOIN FeeDepositDetail ON FeeDepositMaster.nFeeDepositID=FeeDepositDetail.nFeeDepositID WHERE ISNULL(FeeDepositMaster.IsCanceled,0)=0 AND FeeDepositMaster.nStudentInSessionID=@nStudentInSessionID AND nDepositIN IN (@nDepositID) AND FeeDepositDetail.nFeeHeadID in (@tnFeeHeadID) AND nDepositIn IN (SELECT DISTINCT nDepositIn FROM FeeGroupDetail WHERE  nDepositInGroupID in (@tnDepositInGroupID))    
                                    END 
                                    --=========================================================
                                INSERT INTO FeesDueFeeListHeadWise_Temp(nStudentInSessionID,nDepositInGroupID,nDepositIn,nFeeHeadID,nActualFee,nStudFee,nFeePaid,nConcession,nLateFee,nCampusID,cSession)
                                VALUES(@nStudentInSessionID,@tnDepositInGroupID,@nDepositID,@tnFeeHeadID,ISNULL(@nActualFee,0),ISNULL(@nStudFee,0),ISNULL(@nFeePaid,0),ISNULL(@nConcession,0),ISNULL(@nLateFee,0),@nCampusID,@cSession)                                 
                                FETCH NEXT FROM @GetFeeHead INTO @tnFeeHeadID                           
                            END
                    FETCH NEXT FROM @GetDepositInGroup INTO @tnDepositInGroupID     
                    CLOSE @GetFeeHead
                    DEALLOCATE @GetFeeHead                      
                 END                    
            FETCH NEXT FROM @GetDepositIn INTO @nDepositID                                   
            CLOSE @GetDepositInGroup
            DEALLOCATE @GetDepositInGroup
         END
        FETCH NEXT FROM @GetStudents INTO @nStudentInSessionID                  
        CLOSE @GetDepositIn
        DEALLOCATE @GetDepositIn
     END
 CLOSE @GetStudents
DEALLOCATE @GetStudents
```

Comment: Yes, it will be slower, known as RBAR (row by agonizing row). This is agonizing just to read it.  Please provide **sample data** and **expected result**.

Comment: Basically you need to join the various tables instead of reading from one table, then using that read to form another read (per row).  Instead of matching through  `IN (subquery...)` each one of those can be refactored as a join condition. nb: There are 20 select keywords, just 10 rows in a cursor fires off about 200 seperate select queries, not surprising it's slow really.

Comment: You mean, I need to replace the three nested CURSORs with JOIN commands?

Comment: I believe so, but I gave up as I really don't know a thing about your data or the purpose of this sp. it seems your inserting into a table, based on some parameters and while I'm confident you can improve the query overall I'm not attempting to do it for you.

Comment: nb `WHERE FeeDepositMaster.dFeeDepositDate<=@dDueUpto` could become `WHERE ( (FeeDepositMaster.dFeeDepositDate<=@dDueUpto and @Ischeckdate=1) or @Ischeckdate <> 1)`

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Your very first line is reading from `@t1`. The most interesting part happens before: How are your various table variables declared and filled? Where is the actual data coming from?